# services.AddSingleton<IJwtAuthenticationManager>(new JwtAuthenticationManager(key)); but jwtAuth needs DatabaseContext and i dont know how to supply

Tags: c#, .net-core

**JwtRepo**
my next step is to
var key = "This is my auth key";
services.AddSingleton(new JwtAuthenticationManager(key));

but since i have DabaseContext as a parameter (new JwtAuthenticationManger(key)) also needs DbContext parameter.

i just cant proceed without the DbContext parameter and i also dont know how to add a variable that has DbContext value in it

```
    private readonly string key;

    public JwtAuthenticationManager(DatabaseContext context, string key)
    {
        _context = context;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public string Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {

        var result = _context.Credentials.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password);

        if (result == null) return null;

        // user is found and create jwt token. 
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
                }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),

            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature
            )
        };

        // get the token 
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor); // will give back the security token
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to be a Singleton lifetime?

Comment: Create some class like `JwtAuthenticationManagerSettings` with property `key`, register it and use it instead of `key` parameter in `JwtAuthenticationManager` ctor.

Comment: @GuruStron Please don't answer in comments. Write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is okay to have this class as transient or at least scoped, you can use the overload that accepts a factory method:

```
collection.AddTransient<JwtAuthenticationManager>(
    provider => new JwtAuthenticationManager(provider.GetService<DatabaseContext>(), key))
```

If it *needs* to be a singleton, that is a problem, because your DatabaseContext is probably Scoped. And you cannot have a Scoped service as parameter to a singleton service, that would be weird and a source of errors.

Comment: Thank you! can you recommend a good resource on learning how to add authentication and authorization into mvc dotnet core web app c#?